# How to Get All Custom Fields attached to a project on Workfront ATTASK? And Update Fields Also

Tags: attask, workfront-api

How to get all Custom Fields attached to a project on Workfront? And Update Fields Also

Currently I am working on AtTask integration with my application. I have a scenario where I need to add some custom_fields with project.

So I start with adding one custom_form with required fields and attached to project while creating project through rest API.
My question is that how to get all custom fields? so i fill the fields and update the project custom fields.

Iam only receive the customs fields that have some value but there are lot of fields which is null how to get all custome fields ?
Please Help me to sort out..
Currently i am doing :
Request: 
https://ABC.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api-unsupported/proj/search?apiKey=APIKEY&name=Testing Project Template 5&fields=parameterValues,category

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to get fields that do not contain a value from the project level. This is because they are only added to that project in the database when a value is entered. So when searching for parameterValues on a project only values in the database are returned.

to get this you need to search the catagory for all fields on the category

```
attask/api/v4.0/ctgy/{categoryID}?fields=categoryParameters:parameter
```

categoryID would be the ID of the custom form being attached to the project this will give you all possible fields on that custom form.